# On-Board Aircraft Detection Sensor Coverage

Tags: geometry

I have a math question related to aviation. I’m trying to find someone to help me calculate the percentage of a volume that a sensor covers. The volume of this shape is unknown.

What is known:

- Aircraft #1 is going at 20 m/s
- Other aircraft are going at 60m/s
- Both aircraft are in level flight
- Aircraft #1 needs a device to warn the pilots when other aircraft are within the detection volume.
- The detection volume is calculated by: NMAC + (12.5 seconds multiplied by the closing rate of the two aircraft in m/s)
- 12.5 seconds is based on the time it takes for aircraft #1 to receive an alert of an intruding aircraft and to complete an avoidance maneuver.
- A Near Mid-Air Collision (NMAC) is defined as two aircraft coming within 500 ft (152 m) horizontal and ± 100 ft (30 m) vertical of each other while in flight.

Question:

- What percentage of the detection volume will be covered with a forward-pointing sensor that has an 80° horizontal FOV, a 50° vertical FOV, and 1200 meter range?
- Since aircraft #1 is moving forward at 20 m/s does that increase the sensor's detection capabilities?

Comment: This is all new to me, so I could easily be mistaken re:  there seems to be conflicting premises. [1] "The (detection) shape is a bubble - this implies that the shape is that of a sphere. [2] "...NMAC is defined as ...". "The detection volume is calculated by...".  This (seems) to imply that the detection shape is that of a rectangular box (i.e. rectangular parallelopiped).  Have I misinterpreted something?

Comment: See also the comment that I left, following the answer of fedja.

Comment: Thank you @user2661923! Would the NMAC volume not be a cylinder? Same with the detection volume?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I didn't think it through.

Comment: @user2661923 No problem! Neither did I, clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: What is written below makes sense only if I understood your definitions correctly.

I assume that both aircraft are in straight and level flight. The "detection volume" (the volume of the part of the space from which the aircraft 2 can in principle enter the NMAC zone of aircraft 1 in 12.5 sec given the velocities but no other information) stretches then 30m up and down vertically (allowing for ascending or descending approaches will change the answer quite a bit). The planar shape of it is a circle of radius $152+12.5\times 60=902m$ centered $12.5\times 20=250m$ ahead of aircraft 1. So the total volume is $60\pi\times 902^2\approx 153\times 10^6\,m^3$.

Since $902+250+30<1200$, the radar range is more than sufficient and the limitations come from the field of view only. I assume that $80^\circ$ horizontal FOV means $40^\circ$ left and right and similarly for the vertical FOV. The detected cross-section within the dangerous region $x$ meters ahead of aircraft 1 is then a rectangle whose half-sides are
$\min(x\tan(25^\circ), 30)$ and $\min(x\tan(40^\circ),\sqrt{902^2-(x-250)^2})$.

Thus, the volume of the part of the dangerous region detectable by the radar is
$$
4\int_0^{1152}\min(x\tan(25^\circ), 30)\min(x\tan(40^\circ),\sqrt{902^2-(x-250)^2})\,dx\approx 53\times 10^6\,m^3
$$
(I just used numeric integration here though, in principle, all antiderivatives are elementary).

Thus, in this case the answer is $53/153\approx 35\%$.

I'm not sure that the volume comparison is a reasonable measure of the effectiveness of the radar though. I would rather consider all possible initial positions and flight directions of aircraft 2 (taking uniform measure on each) that can lead to the NMAC and count the percentage of those that would result in a timely detection by the radar. That computation yields an answer about $30\%$, which is pretty close but slightly less optimistic. However you asked and I answered :-)

And yes, the forward velocity improves the chance of timely detection in both computations.

*Edit:* An alternative approach to the radar effectiveness estimate.

Suppose that aircraft 1 takes off and flies in a straight and level flight for some not too small time $T$ at 20m/s and then lands. Suppose also that aircraft 2 takes off simultaneously with aircraft 1 from random point uniformly distributed in some big region (the exact shape doesn't matter; all that is important is that it contains all locations from which aircraft 2 can in principle collide with aircraft 1 during the flight) and flies in random direction (again, distributed uniformly between -180 and 180) at 60m/s. The effectiveness of radar is going to be measured as the

*conditional probability that the detection will be made at least 12.5 seconds before aircraft 2 enters the NMAC configuration with aircraft 1 conditioned upon the event that the aircraft are on the NMAC course*.

Note that the vertical FOV is good enough: the whole vertical range from $-30m$ to $30m$ is covered at the horizontal distance $30/tan(25^\circ)\approx 64m$, so if the vertical FOV matters for the detection, the detection already occurred way too late. Also the reduction in the radar range because of the vertical displacement is just from 1200m to $\sqrt{1200^2-30^2}>1199m$, which is negligible. Thus we can think that everything happens on the plane.

Let us fix the direction aircraft 2 is flying in. Then if $v_{1,2}$ are the velocity vectors of aircraft 1 and aircraft 2 respectively, the region on the plane where aircraft 2 can take off to intercept the circle of radius 152m around aircraft 1 is essentially a strip of width 304m and length $T|v_1-v_2|$ in the direction of $v=v_1-v_2$ from the takeoff position of aircraft 1 (yellow strip on Figure 1)
[image: Figure 1]
If $T$is not too small, the area of this strip is mainly proportional to $|v|$, so if $P(v)$ is the probability that the aircraft 2 will be detected in time when approaching from the relative (to aircraft 1) direction $-v$, then the conditional probability in question is
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} P(v)|v|d\theta/\int_0^{2\pi}|v|d\theta
$$
where $\theta$ is the direction of $v_2$.

Now, for a fixed $\theta$ and the corresponding vector $v$, we have several possibilities. If $v$ makes an angle with $v_1$ less than on the next figure, then the detection will occur on the outer range of the radar for the entire strip, which, as we know, is always good enough.
[image: Figure 2]
The green angle here is $\arcsin \frac{152}{1200}\approx 7^\circ$. So, all aircraft coming at an angle $33^\circ$ or less will be detected on time.

As the angle increases, the probability $P(v)$ drops steadily from $1$ to $0$ (one can derive an exact formula, but the decay is nearly linear for all practical purposes and occurs quite fast, so I'll not bother you with that unless you ask me to). When the angle is exactly $40^\circ$, only one half of the aircraft (those starting above the magenta line in the strip on the next picture) will be detected.
[image]
Then you'll eventually hit the situation when even the aircraft coming along the top boundary of the strip on the next picture  will be detected too late. Beyond that point the radar will be useless (i.e., $P(v)=0$).
[image]
The computations show that the corresponding green angle is about $9^\circ$.

Thus, replacing the gradual decay of $P$ with the sharp cutoff at $40^\circ$ (which corresponds to $|\theta|\approx 52.5^\circ$, we see that our conditional probability is about
$$
\int_{0^\circ}^{52^\circ}|v(\theta)|d\theta/\int_{0^\circ}^{180^\circ}|v(\theta)|d\theta\approx 0.36
$$
which turns out about the same as the volume ratio (my original 30% was based on the idea that the dangerous takeoff region for aircraft 2 has the same area regardless of its velocity direction, but I later realized that is false in this model).
Here $|v|=\sqrt{20^2+60^2+2\times 20\times 60\cos\theta}$ by the cosine theorem.

There is a geometric reason why this result almost coincides with the volume computation if the radar range is sufficient to prevent the head-on collision and the speed of aircraft 1 is substantially smaller that that of aircraft 2, but if these conditions are not satisfied, the results may diverge a lot.

Comment: **To the OP**: $$\int \sqrt{~a^2 - (cx + d)^2 ~} ~dx$$ is routinely handled by the trig substitution $(cx + d) = a\sin(t).$

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. Yes, you were correct to assume both aircraft are in straight and level flight. Yes, 40° left and right, similarly for the vertical FOV. For now, don't take into consideration ascending or descending aircraft since I will be trying to argue that ascending and descending aircraft will not exist near the operation I'm proposing. So the NMAC and detection volume would be cylindrical? Or is it a sphere, or Ellipsoid?

Comment: @ChristopherWhite If the definition is as I stated, then it is cylindrical. Again, the detection volume is defined in my post as the region in the space from which aircraft 2 can in principle enter into an NMAC configuration with aircraft 1 within the next 12.5 seconds moving at the speed of 60 m/s.

Comment: Thanks @fedja! Can you please elaborate on how you calculated the answer to the approach you described in the final paragraph?

Comment: @ChristopherWhite Sure. But I'll do it a bit later today: it requires a few pictures to make it clear, so I'll need to draw them but I'll have to go in about 15 minutes. Just check this thread today in the evening or tomorrow in the morning. I'll post by then :-)

Comment: Thank you so much @fedja ! When you said "Since 902+350+30<1200" I assume you mean "902, 350, 30 < 1200"? Do we also have to consider that the sensor is mounted on aircraft #1 which is 250 meters back from the center of the cylinder? If yes, the range should still be sufficient: 902+250= 1152 meters, still under 1200 meters.

Comment: @ChristopherWhite Yes, $350$ was a typo; it should be $250$ (otherwise the inequality even fails). As to $+30$, it technically should be $\sqrt{(902+250)^2+30^2}<1200$ (the Pythagorean theorem for the case when aircraft 2 is 30m above or below the aircraft 1), but even the crude triangle inequality gives the sufficient estimate, though I should say that the range is too close to the useful threshold: drop it by mere 100m and the head on collision approach will be detected too late. I would recommend 1500m minimum but formally you are within the limits. Still working on pictures :-)

Comment: @fedja Thank you for the clarification. The manufacturer of the sensor I'm considering claims to have a 93.2% detection rate @ 1200m with a maximum detection range of 1.9 km. It's possible to use up to five of these sensors to gain something near 360° horizontal FOV. I need to detect 70% of the aircraft in the detection volume.

Comment: @ChristopherWhite OK, I posted a brief explanation of the alternative computation. It actually gives pretty much the same result in your case, but the physical meaning is different: your idea seems to be that aircraft 2 suddenly appears at random point in the detection volume and mine is that it starts at a random spot and is on the collision course. Which one makes more sense may depend on the actual setup you have. Apologies for the delay.